# Difference between document type and key values type in couchbase

Tags: java, couchbase

I have some doubt regarding the key value storage in couchbase. Normally we store data as document. I have some questions.

1. What is the difference between document type and key-value type?
2. How can i achieve couchbase key - value storage in java ? Can you explain with a small example.
3. what is the benefit of storing as key-value?

   {

"name":"xxx",

"age":"yyy"

}

How ican i store this document as key value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. A document type in Couchbase means that the value is in json form. A key-value type just means that the value is a blob and Couchbase won't be able to interpret the data for some of its features. For example, if you store a value in non-json (eg. key-value) form then it is not indexable.
2. In Couchbase, every piece of data is stored in key-value form, but if the value is in json form then the value contains a document.
3. Storing data in key value form makes sharding data very easy to do. All NoSQL databases have some form of auto-sharding mechanism built in to them and the reason that they are efficient is because of the key-value nature of the data they contain.
4. In one of the Couchbase SDKs there should be a set API. The API usually looks something like this set(String key, Object value). You should fill out this function something like this set("my_key", "{\"name\":\"xxx\",\"age":\"yyy"}". To retrieve the document use the key.

Comment: I got idea about document .can you please give a sample to store  a student whole details using  the key value  ??

Comment: You can think of the document type as a subset of the key-value type. In the example I gave in my answer "my_key" is the key and the json is the value. A non-json example would be if you serialized your value (think Java serialization for example). This would be a binary value that your client would be able to deserialize into an object.